# How can I parse a string value in one table to join with values in another table

Tags: sql, parsing, join, ssms, ssms-2012

I  have an issue where to create a report, I need two tables to join that don't have any way to join. I did find a way they could potentially join, but it's complicated.

There is table A, which contains a column called select_criteria. Here are some examples of 3 values it contains:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM(TRANSCRIPTDETAIL.CREDIT_BILLING) FROM SOMETABLE WHERE   ((  STUDENTFINANCIAL.TUITION_EXEMPTION  =   'EMPFT'     )    OR     (   STUDENTFINANCIAL.TUITION_EXEMPTION  =   'EMPPT'     )))   

SELECT DISTINCT SUM(TRANSCRIPTDETAIL.CREDIT_BILLING) FROM SOMETABLE WHERE   (   STUDENTFINANCIAL.TUITION_EXEMPTION  =   'PART50'    )
```

In table B, I have a column called tuition_exemption, which contains values like:

```
EMPFT

EMPPT

PART50
```

At the tail end of the whole value within the column in table A, there are the tuition exemption codes that match the values in table B.

Is there a way using MSSQL where I can parse out the codes from the long statement in select_criteria, so that they perfectly match the codes from table B? This is my thought on a way to join up table A and table B like I need to do. The other complication is that there is a 1:many connection between select_criteria and a tuition_exemption value, but a 1:1 connection between a tuition_exemption value and a select_criteria value.

So in the end, the join between the two tables should print, in one example, the same select_criteria value twice (I am referencing the first value in my list above from table A), but in those two rows, the two different tuition_exemption values (EMPFT and EMPPT). Or in the case of table A example 2, it would be printed once and match up to PART50 once.

I am stuck here. I have a statement that successfully grabs the select_criteria values I want:

```
SELECT select_criteria
WHERE (
select_criteria LIKE '%EMPFT%' OR
select_criteria LIKE '%EMPPT%' OR
select_criteria LIKE '%PART50%' OR
)
```

But what I need to do is this. When it grabs the select_criteria values I want, I then want to print to a new column in this table the code it matches up to. Those codes are values in table B like  'EMPFT', 'EMPPT' and 'PART50'. That is why I was thinking of basically parsing out the codes from select_criteria, and printing them into the new column in table A. That way table A and table B have a value to match up on and I write run my report. I just don't now how to do it in SQL. I kind of know in Perl, but was hoping to just do all of this in SSMS 2012.

Thanks for any help!

byobob

Answer (score 0):

You can use any expression which returns a boolean as a join criteria. Since LIKE returns a bool, you should be able to just do this:

```
select *
from tableA
join tableB
on tableA.select_criteria like '%' + tableB.codecolumn + '%'
```

Comment: I tried this as you suggested, however it comes out with the codecolumn from table B empty, and tableA with values